# On the continuity of $\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^3}$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Is $$\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^3}$$continuous at the point $(0,0)$?

I have tried different paths to obtain different values of the limit but every path seems to lead to the conclusion that the limit is 0. Wish if someone comes up with a path that does not produce a limit 0.

Comment: The function as described is undefined at $(0, 0)$. I'm sure you meant the function $$\begin{cases} 0,& 
x = y = 0 \\ \frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^3},& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky and I have made a mistake, thanks pointing out. As @anirudh b has indicated that with $y^{3}=-x^{2}+x^{5}$, the expression goes to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Except...
What if $y<0$, $x=(-y)^{3/2}+y^4$? Now if $y\rightarrow 0^-$, $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$. But
$$\begin{align}\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^3} & =\frac{(-y)^{3/2}y^3+y^7}{-y^3+2(-y)^{3/2}y^4+y^8+y^3} \\
& =\frac{(-y)^{3/2}y^3-(-y)^{3/2}(-y)^{3/2}y^4}{2(-y)^{3/2}y^4-(-y)^{3/2}(-y)^{3/2}y^5} \\
& =\frac{1-(-y)^{3/2}y}{2y-(-y)^{3/2}y^2}\end{align}$$
Since
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow0^-}1-(-y)^{3/2}y=1$$
and
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow0^-}2y-(-y)^{3/2}y^2=0$$
We approach $-\infty$ along this path so the function is discontinuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: I don't understand how to derive $1-(-y)^{3/2}y^{4}...$

Comment: You are right, showing an additional step reveals that I made an error, but it wasn't an important one and I still stand by my result. Note that when $y<0$, $x=(-y)^{3/2}$, the function is undefined, so we just choose a path that gets close enough to this as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$

Comment: take path $y^3 = -x^2+x^5$, given expression =$\frac{x(-x^2+x^5)}{x^2+(-x^2+x^5)}= \frac{x^3(-1+x^3)}{x^5} = \frac{-1+x^3}{x^2} \to \infty$ as $x\to 0$, so f discontinuous at (0,0). can u pls have a look at below proof?

Comment: @anirudh b, it is $-\infty$ because the numerator is $-1$ when $x\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: yes u r right.... did not see the sign

Answer (score 0):

for $\epsilon > 0$, $|x| < \delta, |y| < \delta, -\delta < x,y < \delta, \frac{1}{x} > \frac{-1}{\delta}, \frac{1}{y} > \frac{-1}{\delta}, 1-\delta<1+y<1+\delta, \frac{1}{1+y}< 1/(1-\delta)$

choose $\delta \in (\frac{\epsilon-\sqrt{\epsilon^2+4\epsilon}}{2},\frac{\epsilon+\sqrt{\epsilon^2+4\epsilon}}{2})$

$|\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^3}-0| < \frac{\delta^4}{\delta^2(1-\delta)} =\frac{\delta^2}{(1-\delta)} < \epsilon$

So the given function is continuous

But i have a doubt here. how can we say f has removable singularity at $(0,0)$

Comment: That $x>-\delta$ you cannot flip over to get $1/x>-1/\delta$. Consider if $x$ is negative and positive both cases.

Comment: can u pls tell me why? say we have $-a<x<a $ means $(1/a) < (1/x) < -(1/a)$ which i feel is perfectly valid. Actually f is discontinuous at(0,0). It means i should not be able to prove given expression < $\epsilon$. I am not able to find where i went wrong. It seems right to me

Comment: Okay, one thing, $x$ could be equal to zero (of course then $y$ cannot be zero, because limit excludes the point $(0,0)$) so flipping over to get $1/x$ is just not legitimate. It seems that then you always approach $(x,y)$ to $(0,0)$ by keeping both $x\ne 0, y\ne 0$, but this is not necessarily the case for limit.

Comment: Yes, now i got it. thnks.